# How to find a pattern in a string

Tags: python, regex

I am stuck while finding the pattern position in a string. The string is of 6 characters and consist of **only uppercase letter(A-Z)** or **digits (0-9)**.

```
check_string = 'I have a string 09A4N5'
```

I have to find the position of **'09A4N5'** which could be any other string in a similar format. I tried with the regular expression and was able to find the get the below mentioned solution which gives the position of the word *'string'*.

```
re.search('\w+\w+\w+\w+\w+\w',check_string).start()
9
```

Comment: If you are only interested in uppercase letters and strings, use an appropriate character set (`[...]`).

Comment: `([A-Z0-9])\w+` This will work.

Comment: you don't need regex for that, a for loop with if/else for `str.isupper()` & `str.isdigit()` will be sufficient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
m = re.search(r'\b[A-Z0-9]{6}\b', check_string)
if m:
    print(m.group())  # => 09A4N5
    print(m.start(0)) # => 16
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/PKUj44) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vGJMM5/1).

**Pattern details**

- `\b` - a word boundary

  - `[A-Z0-9]`  - an uppercase ASCII letter or digit
  - `{6}` - exactly six times
- `\b` - word boundary.

If you want to require at least one digit and at least one uppercase letter in the regex, use

```
r'\b(?=[A-Z]*\d)(?=\d*[A-Z])[A-Z0-9]{6}\b'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vGJMM5/2). Here,

- `(?=[A-Z]*\d)` - requires at least one digit
- `(?=\d*[A-Z])` - requires at least one uppercase letter

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Just saw it's always six characters.

You want to search for either `A-Z` or `0-9` and combinations of those. With `[..]` you can define a character set:

```
re.findall(r"[A-Z0-9]{6}", check_string)
```

the `{6}` says, that you want exactly 6 characters.
The position is found by `search`:

```
res = re.search(r"[A-Z0-9]{6}", check_string)
res.span()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
check_string = 'I have a string 09A4N5'

for i, x in enumerate(check_string.split()):
    if len(x) < 6 or any([ i.islower() for i in x ]):
        continue
    else:
        idx = check_string.index(x)
        match = x

print('position:', idx, '- string:', match)
# position: 16 - string: 09A4N5
```